# Error during installation MySQL 8.0 on Debian 10

Tags: mysql, debian

I am trying to install MySQL on Debian 10, I'm doing everything according to instuction but I get error shown below. Can somebody help me solve this probem ?

```
matt@debian:~$ sudo apt install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-community-server (= 8.0.17-1debian10) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: You probably skipped an instruction. Go back to the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the attached repositories with the `apt policy` command. Remove old repositories or actualize the release name.
2. Clean the packages cache (`apt clean`).
3. Update the packages lists (`apt update`).
4. Check the current state of packages with the `apt-get check`.
5. Search the suitable packages (`apt search mysql-server`).
6. Check the policy for your packages (`apt policy mysql-server` and `apt policy mysql-community-server`).
7. Likely issue is caused by some forgotten record somewhere in the sources lists.

Comment: Thanks, I had to install each required package manually (mysql-community-server-core, mysql-community-client, etc..) than it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem because of apt pin.
set mysql pin priority to 900 fixed my problem

```
#/etc/apt/preferences.d/mysql.pref

Package: *
Pin: release o=MySQL
Pin-Priority: 900
```

Answer (score -1):

this tutorial https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-mysql-8-0-on-debian-linux/ helped me with such a problem (Debian 10)

Step 1: Update Debian Before MySQL 8.0 Installation

**sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade**

Step 2: Install Required Packages For MySQL 8.0 Installation

**sudo apt install dirmngr software-properties-common apt-transport-https curl lsb-release ca-certificates -y**

Step 3: Import the MySQL Community Repository

**curl -fsSL https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022 | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/mysql.gpg > /dev/null**

**echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mysql.gpg] http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian $(lsb_release -sc) mysql-8.0" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list**

Step 4: Install MySQL 8.0 on Debian via APT Command

**sudo apt install mysql-community-server**

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/571008)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).